# How to remove the content in the td tag using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table defined like

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
       <input type='text' />
    </td>
    <td>
      <button id ='first'>Button</button>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type='text' />
   </td>
 </tr>
```

```
$("#first").live('click',function(){
    $(this).prev().remove();
    $(this).remove();
});
```

How can i remove the previous element in the `td`. But i don't want to remove the `td`

Comment: There are no previous elements for `#first`.

Comment: What i mean is i want to remove the textbox before the `td` of the `button`

Comment: $(this).parent().prev().find('input').remove(); ? parent of button is td element which then take previous td element and find input value inside it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to remove the complete contents of that previous TD (rather than a specific INPUT element), this will work:

```
$(document).on("click", "#first", function() {
    $(this).closest("td").prev().empty();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

http://jsfiddle.net/sfHBn/1/

```
$(document).on("click", "#first", function() {
    $(this).closest("td").prev().html("");
});
```

This will remove all content in previous `td` tag.

Answer (score 2):

You should go up the DOM tree until parent `<td>`, then get previous `<td>`, find `<input>` inside and remove it. You should use `on()` with event delegation instead of deprecated `live()`:

```
$(document).on("click", "#first", function() {
    $(this).closest("td").prev().find("input").remove();
});
```

Note, that instead of `document` you may use any other *static* parent element of `#first`.

Comment: I jst given a sample but it may be a input or div or select element

Answer (score 0):

Here is the one liner to achieve.

```
     $(this).closest("td").prev().remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use `.on()` instead because `.live()` is been now removed from the jQuery version 1.9+:

```
$(document).on('click', "#first", function(){
   $(this).closest('td').prev().children().remove();
});
```

Click the `#first` button and get to the `.closest()` `<td>` and get the `.prev()` element which is a `<td>` as well then `.remove()` its `.children()`.